What's the explicit value of this determinant
Let $n\ge2$ be a positive integer, and let $b_1,\cdots,b_n, c_1,\cdots, c_n$ be variables.
Recently, I met the following determinant:
$$\det A=\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & b_1+c_1 & b_1^2+c_1^2 & \cdots & b_1^{n-1}+c_1^{n-1}\\
1 & b_2+c_2 & b_2^2+c_2^2 & \cdots & b_2^{n-1}+c_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & b_n+c_n & b_n^2+c_n^2 & \cdots & b_n^{n-1}+c_n^{n-1}
\end{array}\right|.$$
I want to know if there is an exact formula for this determinant. Thank you very much!

Looks almost like a sum of two Vandermonde matrices.   Then look here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3758359/1070376

Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by "formula". Expanding a determinant using $n!$ terms is also a formula. Already for $n=3$ the corresponding polynomial is irreducible, as I just checked, so no cute factorization to be expected.

+1. For a question like this, a good first thing to do would be to estimate the largest integer $t_n$ where $\det(A)=0\mod t_n$ whenever $A$ is integer valued. I got $(t_1,\dots,t_5)=(2, 2, 4, 24, 576)$ and $t_n=2\cdot 1!\cdots(n-1)!$ (these are the superfactorials, A000178) for all $n$ (I have no proof of this though).

What about the determinant of the sum of $m$ Vandermonde matrices? Let $t_{m,n}$ be the largest integer where $\det(A)=0\mod t_{m,n}$ whenever $A$ is the sum of $m$ distinct $n\times n$-Vandermonde matrices where the variables are integers. Then $t_{m,n}=m\cdot 1!\dots(n-1)!$ according to my computer calculations.

I am always getting a determinant of zero in fields of characteristic 2. Furthermore, in the finite field $F_q$, I am always getting zero determinant as long as $n>q$.

If $c_1,\dots,c_r$ are integers, and $A_1,\dots,A_r$ are $n\times n$-Vandermonde matrices whose variables are integers, then $\det(c_1A_1+\dots+c_rA_r)$ is a multiple of $(c_1+\dots+c_r)\cdot 1!\cdots(n-1)!$ in all my computer experiments.

@JosephVanName: The extra $2$ factor in your formula for $t_n$ is spurious -- I assume you have replaced the $1$s in the first column by $b_i^0 + c_i^0 = 2$'s, which caused the determinant to get scaled by $2$.

We can rewrite the determinant of a linear combination of Vandermonde matrices as a Wronskian determinant of polynomials.$\DeclareMathOperator{\Det}{Det}\DeclareMathOperator{\Diag}{Diag}$

Let $V(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ denote the Vandermonde matrix with indeterminates $c_1,\dots,c_n$,
let $W(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ denote the Wronskian matrix of the functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$,
let $\Diag(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ denote the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $d_1,\dots,d_n$, and
finally, as the Wronskian and Vandermonde matrices are pointing in different directions, let $VW(c_1,\dots,c_n)=\big(c_j^{n-i}\big)_{i,j}$.

Suppose that $f_i(x)=(x+c_i)^{n-1}$. Then
$$
\frac{d^m}{dx^m}f_i(x)=\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(x+c_i)^n=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}(x+c_i)^{n-m},
$$ so
$$
\begin{split}
W(f_1,\dots,f_n)(0) & = W\big((x+c_1)^{n-1},\dots,(x+c_n)^{n-1}\big)\\
&=\Diag\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-i)!}\right)_{i=1}^n\cdot VW\big((x+c_1)^{n-1},\dots,(x+c_n)^{n-1}\big).
\end{split}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
\Det\left(\sum_{k=1}^m r_k\cdot W((x+c_{k,1})^{n-1},\dots,(x+c_{k,n})^{n-1})\right)&=\Det\left(\sum_{k=1}^mr_k\cdot\Diag\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-i)!}\right)_{i=1}^n\cdot VW\big((x+c_{k,1})^{n-1},\dots,(x+c_{k,n})^{n-1}\big)\right)\\
&=\frac{(n-1)!^n}{1!\cdots(n-1)!}\cdot\Det\left(\sum_{k=1}^m r_k\cdot VW\big((x+c_{k,1})^{n-1},\dots,(x+c_{k,n})^{n-1}\big)\right)\\
& =\frac{(n-1)!^n}{1!\cdots(n-1)!}\cdot(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\cdot\Det\left(\sum_{k=1}^m r_k\cdot V\big((x+c_{k,1})^{n-1},\dots,(x+c_{k,n})^{n-1}\big)\right).
\end{split}
$$

What is $r_k$? And how to understand $r_k\sum_{k=1}^n$ ?

@MaxAlekseyev Sorry for that typo. It should be good now.

$r_k$ is still not defined.
